# How to redirect warnings to the screen?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am writing code C code that uses ROS and my OS is Linux.
I also use launch file in order to run my program.

**My problem:**
I don´t see the warnings on the screen after compilation. The only thing I am able to see is this message:

> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< guiPackage
> [PASS] [ 4.21 seconds ] -- WARNING: 2
> compiler warnings

**My Questions:**

1. Is this problem connected to the launch file or not?
2. Whatever the answer for 1 is, how can I see the warnings on the shell screen of Linux in this case?

Thank you all for your time,
Felix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12609/how-to-redirect-warnings-to-the-screen?/) by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Felix,

this cannot be connected to any launch file, since the launch file is not used during compile time.

There are two ways of seeing the warnings:

1. There is a message at the beginning of the `rosmake` output, which looks something like this:

   `[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/martin/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120112-135426`

All logs (including the warnings) are in files below that directory.

2. You can run `make` instead of `rosmake` to see the warnings. Note however that `make` doesn't build the dependencies. Also you'll probably need to run `make clean` beforehand to see anything interesting going on.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-12**:
Also you can run rosmake with verbose turned on '-V' option.